# Attribute Error for Adafruit SSD 1306

Tags: python, display

When I try and run code that uses AdafruitSSD1306, it gives an attribute error that looks like this: [image]

Here is my code,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import Adafruit_SSD1306
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
import os



def display_time():
  # Collect current time and date
  if(time_format):
  current_time = time.strftime("%I:%M")
  else:
  current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M")

  current_date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

  # Clear image buffer by drawing a black filled box
  draw.rectangle((0,0,width,height), outline=0, fill=0)

  # Set font type and size
  font = ImageFont.truetype('Minecraftia.ttf', 35)

  # Position time
  x_pos = (disp.width/2)-(string_width(font,current_time)/2)
  y_pos = 2 + (disp.height-4-8)/2 - (35/2)

  # Draw time
  draw.text((x_pos, y_pos), current_time, font=font, fill=255)

  # Set font type and size
  font = ImageFont.truetype('Minecraftia.ttf', 8)

  # Position date
  x_pos = (disp.width/2)-(string_width(font,current_date)/2)
  y_pos = disp.height-10

  # Draw date
  draw.text((x_pos, y_pos), current_date, font=font, fill=255)

  # Draw the image buffer
  disp.image(image)
  disp.display()

def display_social():
  from exchanges.Coindesk import Coindesk
  #Collect prices
  get_current_price(currency='USD')
  # Collect social media subscribers/followers/... by parsing webpages
  Bitcoin = get_current_price(currency='USD')

  # Put data in lists that can be iterated over
  channels = ["Bitcoin"]
  Subscribers = [Bitcoin]

  # Clear image buffer by drawing a black filled box
  draw.rectangle((0,0,width,height), outline=0, fill=0)

  # Set font type and size
  font = ImageFont.truetype('Minecraftia.ttf', 8)

  # Iterate over lists
  for i in range(0, 5):
  # Position channel name
  x_pos = 2
  y_pos = 2 + (((disp.height-4)/5)*i)

  # Draw channel name
  draw.text((x_pos, y_pos), channels[i], font=font, fill=255)

  # Position subcribers/followers/...
  x_pos = disp.width - 2 - string_width(font, subscribers[i])
  y_pos = 2 + (((disp.height-4)/5)*i)

  # Draw subcribers/followers/...
  draw.text((x_pos, y_pos), subscribers[i], font=font, fill=255)

  # Draw the image buffer
  disp.image(image)
  disp.display()

def display_network():
  # Collect network information by parsing command line outputs
  ipaddress = os.popen("ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'").read()
  netmask = os.popen("ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'Mask' | awk -F: '{print $4}'").read()
  gateway = os.popen("route -n | grep '^0.0.0.0' | awk '{print $2}'").read()
  ssid = os.popen("iwconfig wlan0 | grep 'ESSID' | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F\\\" '{print $2}'").read()

  # Clear image buffer by drawing a black filled box
  draw.rectangle((0,0,width,height), outline=0, fill=0)

  # Set font type and size
  font = ImageFont.truetype('Minecraftia.ttf', 12)

  # Position SSID
  x_pos = 2
  y_pos = 2

  # Draw SSID
  draw.text((x_pos, y_pos), ssid, font=font, fill=255)

  # Set font type and size
  font = ImageFont.truetype('Minecraftia.ttf', 8)

  # Position IP
  y_pos += 12 + 10 

  # Draw IP
  draw.text((x_pos, y_pos), "IP: "+ipaddress, font=font, fill=255)

  # Position NM
  y_pos += 10 

  # Draw NM
  draw.text((x_pos, y_pos), "NM: "+netmask, font=font, fill=255)

  # Position GW
  y_pos += 10

  # Draw GW
  draw.text((x_pos, y_pos), "GW: "+gateway, font=font, fill=255)

  # Draw the image buffer
  disp.image(image)
  disp.display()

def display_custom(text):
  # Clear image buffer by drawing a black filled box
  draw.rectangle((0,0,width,height), outline=0, fill=0)

  # Set font type and size
  font = ImageFont.truetype('Minecraftia.ttf', 8)

  # Position SSID
  x_pos = (width/2) - (string_width(font,text)/2)
  y_pos = (height/2) - (8/2)

  # Draw SSID
  draw.text((x_pos, y_pos), text, font=font, fill=255)

  # Draw the image buffer
  disp.image(image)
  disp.display()

def string_width(fontType,string):
  string_width = 0

  for i, c in enumerate(string):
  char_width, char_height = draw.textsize(c, font=fontType)
  string_width += char_width

  return string_width

# Set up GPIO with internal pull-up
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# 128x64 display with hardware I2C
disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_64(rst=24)

# Initialize library
disp.begin()

# Get display width and height
width = disp.width
height = disp.height

# Clear display
disp.clear()
disp.display()

# Create image buffer with mode '1' for 1-bit color
image = Image.new('1', (width, height))

# Load default font
font = ImageFont.load_default()

# Create drawing object
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

prev_millis = 0
prev_social = 0
display = 0
time_format = True

while True:
  millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

  # Software debouncing
  if((millis - prev_millis) > 250):
  # Cycle through different displays
  if(not GPIO.input(12)):
  display += 1
  if(display > 2):
  display = 0
  prev_millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

  # Trigger action based on current display
  elif(not GPIO.input(16)):
  if(display == 0):
  # Toggle between 12/24h format
  time_format = not time_format
  time.sleep(0.01)
  elif(display == 1):
  # Reconnect to network
  display_custom("reconnecting wifi ...")
  os.popen("sudo ifdown wlan0; sleep 5; sudo ifup --force wlan0")
  time.sleep(0.01)
  elif(display == 2):
  # Refresh social media now
  display_custom("fetching data ...")
  display_social()
  time.sleep(0.01)
  prev_millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

  if(display == 0):
  display_time()
  prev_social = 0
  elif(display == 1):
  display_network()
  prev_social = 0
  elif(display == 2):
  # Only fetch social media data every 5 minutes when active
  if((millis - prev_social) > 300000):
  display_custom("fetching data ...")
  display_social()
  prev_social = millis

  time.sleep(0.1)
```

I was wondering what I am doing wrong, as I have git cloned the Adafruit SSD1306 into the same path and it still doesn't work. How should I go about fixing it?